# Deep object validation

Tags: grails

I have 3 classes

```
class Company {
    String company_name
}

class Job {
    String job_name
    Company company
}
class Person {
    String person_name
    Job job
}
```

How can I check if a position is really existing from an existing company and it is vacant (no Person is on it) or in other words there is existing Job object with existing Company of course but no Person has in his constructor  passed  this Job object, here is what I have done,where is my mistake ?

```
if (person==null && job != null && company != null)
{
    def query=Job.where{company.company_name == company_name && job_name == job_name}
    def query2=Person.where {job.job_name == job_name}
    if( query == null && query2 != null )
    {
        def person12 = new Person(job: job, person_name: person_name)
        if (person12.validate() && person12.save()) 
        {
            redirect(url: "https//localhost:8080")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the Job - Person relation one-to-one? If so, it would be a lot easier if you changed it, so Job has a Person in it. and so then you just look if where is a job with specific title and company and worker (Person) is null.

Answer (score 0):

I would relate the classes in other way if possible:

```
class Company {
   String company_name
   static hasMany = [jobs: Job]
}

class Job {
   static belongsTo = [company: Company]
   static hasOne = [person: Person]
   String job_name
}
class Person {
   String person_name
   static belongsTo = [job: Job]
}
```

And then you can create a criteria to know if a job has no person related.

```
List<Job> jobs = Job.withCriteria{
   eq('company', companyObject)
   isNull('person')
}
```

You don't need to validate an object before save it, cause it automatly validated before, and if it is not valid, return false.

```
if (person12.save()) {
   redirect(url: "https//localhost:8080")
}
```